# Hiding div classes when timer ends in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, web, timer

I have a timer script but I am having a few issues with it. Just a day ago, it was working perfectly fine, as intended. Now, the timer no longer hides the div class when it ends. Didn't change the HTML or JavaScript code at all, but for whatever reason it no longer removes the div class.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ' ' + ' ' + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            display.textContent = 'OFFER HAS EXPIRED.';
            $('.formme').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        console.log(parseInt(seconds));
        window.localStorage.setItem('seconds', seconds);
        window.localStorage.setItem('minutes', minutes);
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
    sec = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('seconds'));
    min = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('minutes'));

    if (parseInt(sec) == 0 && parseInt(min) == 0) {
        $('#time').text('OFFER HAS EXPIRED.');
        $('.formme').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
        var start = 5 * 60;

        if (sec > 0 || min > 0) {
            start = parseInt(min * 60) + sec;
        }
        // var start = 60 * 5;
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(start, display);
    }
};
```

On top of that, I used localStorage to prevent the timer from resetting when the webpage is refreshed. However, when the timer is finished, instead of going straight to the "OFFER HAS EXPIRED" text, it counts down from 00:01 then displays the text. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!